# if clicked arround element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

i just wanna ask if there's something like "if clicked arround" in jQuery, i mean, if clicked any element in the page except for one element, or if there a way to make that easily.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use [.not()](https://api.jquery.com/not/)

[event.stoppropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

> Description: Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

```
$('#divID').not('#ElID').click(function(){
       //* code here */ 
});
```

---

Or

[:not()](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```
$('#divID:not("#ElID")').click(function(){
       //* code here */ 
});
```

---

Start Reading [jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/) and [Learning](http://learn.jquery.com/)

---

**Updated After OP's comment.**

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/R2ae5/)</kbd>

[event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) and  [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

```
$('#divID').click(function (event) {
    if (!$(event.target).is('#ElID')) {
        alert('Work');
    }
});
```

---

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/R2ae5/2)</kbd>

Works on click anywhere except element with id `ElID`

```
$('html').click(function (event) {
    if (!$(event.target).is('#ElID')) {
        alert('Work');
    }
});
```

Comment: this is useful, but it does not work if you want to hide a div when you click it, but not when you click it's child div

Comment: What if you want to click outside of `#divID` too, like anywhere else in the page except `#E1ID`.  It seems this should be solved with a delegated event handler.

Comment: @TusharGupta - so why isn't that in your answer?  FYI, delegated event handling would do this for you without even having to have the logic inside the event handler.

Comment: @jfriend00 can you show delegated event handling at work . It will great .

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$(document).on("click", function(event) {               
  if($(event.target).parents().index(yourElement) == -1) {                   
      // your code here
   }        
});
```